# Finger stops moving while the bone keeps going

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I've been trying to transfer over an XNALara model to SFM by using blender. So far I haven't really had too much of an issue but I'm struggling to figure out how to get the fingers to bend properly on the model. This model in particular has his fingers curled up to begin with so it's a little bit harder for me to really pinpoint what my problem is when most examples start with a straight finger.

I have a feeling my problem is mainly with the IK setup when it comes to the bones. The mesh doesn't seem to want to deform with it either even after weight painting but I think it would work out once I get the bone problem out of the way.

[image]

I'm fairly new to blender, really just started last week. Might be evident in the lack of hip bones on the model (Haven't figured that one out just yet)

Anyway the blend file is here: https://www.mediafire.com/?ohg221owj56c7b1

If anyone can give me input I'd be grateful. I've been looking at various tutorials but like I mentioned, it's just kind of difficult since I'm starting on a model that already has posed fingers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the fingers issue is, that vertices of fingers are in Wrist (left and right accordingly) Vertex Groups with weight of 1 and in appropriate fingers Vertex Groups.[image]
Remove them from Wrists Vertex Groups and they will start follow fingers accurately.

---

P.S. Consider removing doubles in the model, there are bunch of those.

Comment: Thank you! I went ahead and removed them from the wrist group and the fingers are moving a lot more smoothly after adjusting the rest of the overlapping vertexes. The mesh is still kind of stretching weird here and there but it's nothing major that can't be solved with a little bit of tweaking. I also went and removed the doubles, which is something I didn't even know about so an extra thanks for teaching me something additional there.